# Edit object value in the array : Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function, that takes and object with id/value props and array of objects as args, looks like so:

```
export const editNote = (editedNote: Note, notes: Notes): Notes => {
notes.find(obj => obj.id === editedNote.id && obj.value === editedNote.value);
return notes;
```

When passing arguments:

```
const data = [{id:0, value:'a'}, {id:1, value:'b'}]
expect(editNote({id:0, value:'z'}, data)).toEqual([{id:0, value:'z'}, {id: 1, value:'b'}]);
```

I still receive an unchanged value:

```
Received:
[{"id": 0, "value": "a"}, {"id": 1, "value": "b"}]
```

Point me please to my mistakes. New to JS and even newer to TS.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect an unchanged value? `editNote` doesn't seem to *do* anything.

Comment: The result of find() isn't being used and you then return the whole notes array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

editNote() just returns notes.
Maybe you meant this:

```
export const editNote = (editedNote: Note, notes: Note[]): Note[] => {
  const note = notes.find(obj => obj.id === editedNote.id);
  note.value = editedNote.value;

  return notes;
}
```